# Energy of a Hamiltonian that is the sum of commuting Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, quantum-statistics

Suppose that $$H=\sum _i H_i\quad\textrm{with}\quad [H_i,H_j]=0 \quad\textrm{for} \quad j\neq i$$ Let $\psi_i$ be a solution to $H_i$ so that $$H_i\psi_i=E_i\psi_i$$Does this always imply that the solution to $H$ is 
$$\psi=\prod _i \psi_i\quad\textrm{with}\quad E=\sum _i E_i$$ in the sense that $$H\psi = E \psi$$
or are more conditions than commutability of the hamiltonians necessary? Please give reference to an appropriate proof.

Comment: How should one interpret $\Pi_i\psi_i$?  On what space do the $\psi_i$ live?  --  Also, I'm pretty sure that the Toric Code is a counterexample to your statement (whatever it precisely is).  (Except that the possible eigenvalues $E$ of $H$ are $E=\sum_i E_i$, with $E_i$ the eigenvalues of $H_i$ -- that part is true.)

Comment: It's hard for me to state my question with full rigour. We thought of $\prod _i \psi_i$ as a separation ansatz. In our special case is $H_i=H_i(X_i, P_i)$, where $X_i$ and $P_i$ are the impuls and position operator for different particles. We showed that the ansatz leads to $E=\sum _i E_i$ by assuming that $\psi_i=\psi_i(X_i, P_i)$, but couldn't really justify this assumption. Our guess is that this assumption is related to the commutability of the hamiltonians. You say that the part with the energies is true, can you provide a sketch on how to prove this part?

Comment: See yu-v's answer: Commuting matrices can be simultaneously diagonalized, so eigenvalues of their sums can always be written as sums of their eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Properly speaking one should require that the spectral measures of single parts of the total Hamiltonian commute. This is however the standard if the parts correspond to independent subsistems, and I interpret this way your question: each part is defined in a single Hilbert space and the total space is the tensor product of them. What finally happens is that the spectrum of the total Hamiltonian is the closure of the sum of the spectra. I do not think one can say further. Restricting to the *point spectrum*,  it turns out that sum of *proper* eigenvalues are eigenvalues, but you can obtain the same result summing different strings of eigenvalues in general. So your claim regarding the form of eigenvectors may fail. (The naive claim should however refer to a basis if eigenvectors of the complete Hamiltonian: in general, one has to take linear combinations of your candidates in case of degenerated eigenvalue of some component Hamiltonian.)

Referring to the general case, where the operators do not live in separated Hilbert spaces, the only result relies on this fact: if $H_1, \ldots, H_n$ are selfadjoint and pairwise commute then there is a selfadjoint operator $A$ such that $H_i=f_i(A)$ for some (Borel) functions $f_i$. Hence $$H=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(A) =: f(A).$$
Hence the spectrum of $H$ is the closure of the image of $R$ through $f$, that is the closure of the sum of the spectra of the $H_i$.

Answer (score 0):

If your Hamiltonian is a sum of commuting Hamiltonians as you write then it is guaranteed that there **exists** a basis that simultaneously diagonalizes all Hamiltonians together, and therefore $E=\sum_{i} E_i$ indeed. If any of the $H_i$ is non-degenerate, then diagonalizing it will generate the unique basis of the eigenstates. However, they will not be $\psi = \prod_i \psi_i$. I assume that in this you mean some tensor-product? If the case is that the parts of the Hamiltonian commute because they operate in orthogonal subspaces of the Hilbert space, then this will be the case. Then you will have to diagonalize each Hamiltonian and indeed proceed as you wrote.

Note, that if the Hamiltonians are degenerate, a choice that diagonalize one of them might not be diagonal in the other, just block-diagonal.

Comment: If the $H_i$ are local Hamiltonians, then the $H_i$ will necessarily be degenerate.  Also, it should be subsystems, not subspaces -- you want a tensor product, not a direct sum (=subspace).

Comment: Thanks to you and @Norbert Schuch I now understand the relation between commutability and total energy. I was able to prove that a common eigenbasis for commuting operators can be found, at least in finite dimensional Hilbertspaces. Sadly I wasn't yet able to grasp the concept of locality that Norbert Schuch mentioned and don't fully understand when subspaces of my Hilbertspace are orthogonal. For example are the position spaces of different electrons in a solid orthogonal? Where I am certain of the orthogonality e.g. is the spin space $\mathbb{C}^2$ of a particle and the position space $L^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly any state of the form $\psi = \otimes_i \psi_i$ will be an eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $E = \sum_i E_i$. But it's possible that there are eigenstates of $H$ that don't factorize, in case there are degeneracies. Consider for instance the case where $H$ is the sum of two harmonic oscillators, having energies $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2 = 2$. Then for any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ the state
$$| \psi \rangle = (\alpha  (a_1^\dagger)^2 + \beta  a_2^\dagger) | \text{vac} \rangle $$
is an eigenstate with energy 2 (since $2\omega_1 = \omega_2 = 2$). (I'm assuming that $H$ is normal-ordered such that the ground state has energy $E = 0$.) Unless $\alpha = 0$ or $\beta = 0$, the state $|\psi \rangle$ does not factorize.

Comment: Yet, there is a *basis* of product eigenstates.